# c++ TensorFlow lite inference of tfhub models

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

BTHOG.

I defined and fine tuned mobile multi lingual bert model constructed using following keras code:

```
bert_preprocess = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_multi_cased_preprocess/3")
bert_encoder = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/mobilebert_multi_cased_L-24_H-128_B-512_A-4_F-4_OPT/1", trainable=True)
i = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name='text')
x = bert_preprocess(i)
x = bert_encoder(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2, name="dropout")(x['pooled_output'])
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name="output")(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(i, x)
```

Eventually I saved the model as tf savedmodel,
And then converted it to tflite version with the following supported ops:

```
tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, # enable TensorFlow Lite ops.
tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS # enable TensorFlow ops.
```

The problem started when I tried to load the tflite converted model using the code from tensorflow github:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/minimal

I get the following errors:

```
ERROR: Select TensorFlow op(s), included in the given model, is(are) not supported by this interpreter. Make sure you apply/link the Flex delegate before inference. For the Android, it can be resolved by adding "org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops" dependency. See instructions: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select
ERROR: Node number 0 (FlexHashTableV2) failed to prepare.
Error at /home/nativ/dev/tflite_inference/minimal.cc:60
```

What can I do to fix those errors?

Answer (score 0):

Your model has some TF ops, and you need to link the Select ops (Also known as flex delegate) which allows you to run TF kernels for the operation(s) that are not available in TFLite as native operations.
Mainly you will need to build the delegate and link it to the binary

```
bazel build -c opt --config=monolithic tensorflow/lite/delegates/flex:tensorflowlite_flex
```

See more details [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select#cc)